# Swift: WebKit webview WKNavigationActionPolicy doesn't work for some sites

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm newbie to swift and now I'm taking the project 4 - make a simple web browser using WKWebView.
Target is: when users're surfing the website, they can tap some links in this website, and following them. The app only permit some sites (create an array and permit sites that it contains).
I'm using WKNavigationActionPolicy.

1/ Case that it works well:

- go to google.com
- enter some site
- user only access to site that in the permit array (for ex, arr = ["apple.com","facebook.com","hackingwithswift.com"])

2/Case that it doesn't work:

- go to danhbanet . com (a website directory for VietNam)
- user tap on link facebook.com on this website but nothing happens (although facebook.com is allowed)

Here is the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zp-b1A0GN6ZWc5d2FYSlZpS28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to your question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hello @TimMalone  ; now I've approached the problem: when I didn't use the policy, the browser permit to follow all link in the website. (access to google.com, search websites and can follow all link). But when goto danhbanet dot com, user can not access anylink